# how to return $and value from getcondition to options.where in app.get()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, sequelize.js

1. i have so many if else conditions but i am posting only one
   condition.
2. Nodejs code here

   ```
     app.get('/v3/details', function(req, res) {
       options.where =  getcondition(req, Sequelize);
       option.include:[{
       model: hp_builders,
       required: true
       },{
       }...etc..]

       });
   hp_property.findAll(options).then(function(results){
      console.log(results);
     });
   ```

   }

so here i am getting where condition in different scenarious.

```
     function getcondition(req, Sequelize) {
      var condition = JSON.parse(req.query.selector);
        if(condition.hasOwnProperty("neighbourhood_id")){
        gettingNeighbourHoodData(condition,function (result) {
          var latitude = result[0].latitude;
            var longitude = result[0].longitude;
                return {
                    $and:[  
                        Sequelize.literal("ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `property_latitude` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( "+latitude+" ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `property_latitude` ) )"+
                            " * COS( RADIANS( "+latitude+" )) * COS( RADIANS( `property_longitude` ) - RADIANS( "+longitude+")) ) * 6380 < 5")
                    ]
                }

            });
        }
        if(){
return ""
        ..etc..
        }

        }
```

my  gettingNeighbourHoodData() function here

```
function gettingNeighbourHoodData(condition,done){
            hp_property_neighbourhood.findAll({
                where: {
                    hp_property_neighbourhood_id: condition.neighbourhood_id
                }
            }) .then(function (result) {
                return  done(result);
            });


           }
```

i am getting the result from gettingNeighbourHoodData but i am unable to return the $and condition obj  from getcondition function to options.where

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to hook a then to the callback as your method is async as folllows:

```
return gettingNeighbourHoodData(condition)
  .then(function (result) {
```

Comment: no i tried with that also but its not waiting for the result due to asynchronous call

Comment: ya ,i tried know but its waiting but not return the exact value because of this return gettingNeighbourHoodData(condition) .